# Why am I getting the error "Class PDO not found" in this situation?

Tags: php, apache, doctrine, pdo

I am getting the following error even though I have PDO installed and included in my php.ini.

What could I be possibly missing? I am using doctrine and codeigniter

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Doctrine\ORM\Query\ParameterTypeInferer::inferType() [<a href='doctrine\orm\query\parametertypeinferer.infertype'>doctrine\orm\query\parametertypeinferer.infertype</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead</p>
<p>Filename: Query/ParameterTypeInferer.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 70</p>

</div><br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'PDO' not found in <b>/home/mrwongs/public_html/engine/application/third_party/Doctrine/ORM/Query/ParameterTypeInferer.php</b> on line <b>70</b><br />
```

My phpinfo can be seen at: http://173.203.85.196/test.php

In my php.ini I have the following 2 lines:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Comment: Are you sure the code running php is actually using the php.ini you are showing us?

Comment: Do a `phpinfo();` and see what the output says about what config file your current setup is using.

Comment: Safest way to check would be `if(!extension_loaded('pdo')) die ('Oops!');`

Comment: @Jon   funny thing is that it appears that PDO is loaded. So now it seems Doctrine can't find it.

Comment: have you tried addressing the timezone setting to see if it's the warning which is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error on a webpage? or running from cli?

php-cli might be using a different php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Restart the apache server. If you haven't done so.